# How to optimize this if-else statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript code like this

```
        if(prog > 100)
          prog = 100;
        else if(prog <0)
          prog = 0;
        else if(typeof prog != 'number')
          prog = 0;
```

It looks bad and ugly. Is there some cooler way to write this in javascript?

Comment: It doesn't look ugly at all. That's how if statements look.

Comment: Hey - isn't it the case taht be it any condition you only need 1 sels i.e. prog = 0 in both else if ; hence you dont need 2 else if and look at using **ternary operation** if its just one else it, hope this help, CHeers\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
 foo = typeof foo == "number" ? foo : 0;
 foo.constrain(0, 100);
```

Which would simply require this to be defined:

```
Number.prototype.constrain = function(min, max) {
  return Math.min(max, Math.max(min, this.valueOf())); 
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you're doing this often... or create a utility object of some kind with the same kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
prog = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, typeof prog == 'number' ? prog : 0));
```

Comment: Well the question talks about ugliness, and I figured, better give him some options as it's a bit subjective

Comment: Also, my one might qualify in the "coolness" part of the question too... Again, quite subjective

Answer (score 1):

prog = (prog > 100 ? 100 : (prog<0 || (typeof prog != 'number') ? 0 : prog));

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce3QT/1/)

Comment: That does not do what is required at all. The original if/else makes sure the number is between zero and one hundred, your ternary operation sets it to zero if it is less than one hundred.

Comment: in the original, if prog is say, 50, or any other number between 0 and 100, it will stay as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof prog != 'number' || prog < 0){
    prog = 0;
} else if (prog > 100) {
    prog = 100;
}
```

- if `prog` is not a number, or less than 0, set to zero *right off the bat*
- else if `prog` is greater than 100, set 100
- anything else, it leaves it alone

the issue was you were evaluating a variable as a number without knowing that it's a number (since you placed the `typeof` check last). if i were to pass `foo` to `prog`, you'd be evaluating 2 times before checking the type. also, you were evaluating two conditions for the same output of `0`, better merge them.

JS does not evaluate the `OR` further when it sees a `TRUE`  in the condition. likewise can be said for the `AND` when it sees a `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Really you should test the type first:

```
if ( typeof prog != 'number' || prog < 0 )
   prog = 0;
else if( prog > 100 )
   prog = 100;
```

Double ternary:

```
prog = typeof prog != 'number'?0:prog;
prog = (prog>100)?100:((prog<0)?0:prog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. It is functionally equivalent, and concise, but not the legible when you come back to the code 12 months from now.

```
prog = (typeof prog != 'number' || prog < 0 ? 0 : (prog > 100 ? 100 : prog));
```

### UPDATE

Here are a couple other ways to do this.

```
prog = (typeof prog != 'number' ? 0 : Math.max(0,Math.min(prog, 100)));
prog = (typeof prog != 'number' || prog < 0 ? 0 : Math.min(prog, 100));
```

I think the first of these two is probably the easiest to understand. Basically, if it isn't a number it sets it to `0`, else it makes sure it is between `0` and `100` which seems to be the logic you are really going after.

Comment: The original doesn't change prog if it is between 0 and 100

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that. I updated my example. It works, but personally I probably wouldn't do it this way. It is pretty hard to read.

Comment: I realized a couple of better ways to do it that are much more legible and convey the intended logic better.